# Why validation error won't appear?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my situation, somehow it doesn't show validation error message even if there was validation error.

For example, I leave these 2 column as empty, and make sure that captcha word is typed in. Then if I try to create new record. It won't show validation error:(
It comes back to the form but no message.

I've been using validation error message all the time in this project , and I never faced this problem.

Anyone can find the problem here?

**Validation in Topic model**

```
validates :title,   
    :presence => {:message => "can't be empty" },    
    :uniqueness => {:message => "choose unique title" },    
    :length => { :maximum => 20, :message => "must be less than 20 characters" }

validates :body,   
    :presence => {:message => "can't be empty" },    
    :length => { :maximum => 500, :message => "must be less than 20 characters" }
```

**Form**

```
<%= form_for([@community, @topic]) do |f| %>
.....

    <%= button_tag( :class => "btn btn-primary") do %>
    Create
    <% end %>

<% end %>
```

**topic_controller**

```
before_filter :simple_captcha_check, :only => [:update, :create]

def simple_captcha_check
    if !simple_captcha_valid?
        flash[:error] = 'wrong captcha'
        if request.put?
            @topic.attributes = params[:topic]  
            render :action => :edit
        elsif request.post?     
            @topic = Topic.new params[:topic]
            render :action => :new
        end
    end
end


def create
    @topic = @community.topics.build (params[:topic]) 
    @topic.user_id = current_user.id

    respond_to do |format|
        if @topic.save
            format.html { redirect_to community_topic_path(@community, @topic), notice: 'Created' }
            format.json { render json: [@community, @topic], status: :created, location: @topic }
        else
            format.html { render action: "new" }
            format.json { render json: @topic.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
    end
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
resources :communities do
     resources :topics
end
```

UPDATE:

**views/layouts/application.html.erb**

```
.....
<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
  <div class="alert alert-<%= name == :notice ? "success" : "error" %>">
    <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&#215;</a>
    <%= content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}" if msg.is_a?(String) %>
  </div>
<% end %>
.....
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flash doesnt appear until the next request. So if you were doing a "Redirect" it would appear.

You are however, doing a render not a redirect. When you render, you return the body of the view itself.

But no worries, If you want to render a view (which is just fine), use the flash like this -

```
flash.now[:error] = 'wrong captcha'
```

The .now ensures that the flash gets flushed in the view of the render within the same request.

EDIT:

The reason your validations dont appear (when captcha fails) is because your before_filter does rendering and stops the create action from even being called. @topic validations only fire at @topic.save in create but since that never gets called (when captcha fails), nothing related to attribute validations appears there.

Secondly, flash.now[:error] will ensure that flash message doesnt get transferred to the next request since you intend to use in the same request's response. If however you set flash[:error] and render, then your flash message WILL appear in the same request's response AND the next request too. This should answer @saurabh's good question above and solve the mystery?

FINAL EDIT:
@MKK had to include an error displaying partial which was missing from the view.

Comment: No. That's not the point. `wrong captcha` appears. As I said regular validation won't appear:(

Comment: validation is not part of the flash, so @AdityaSanghi was answering the question you asked

Comment: Oh my. I'm so sorry for misunderstood. Validation error has to be displayed but why it won't appear? I updated my question.

Comment: But how your `wrong captcha` appearing? According to @AdityaSanghi post, it should not work for `render`.

Comment: @AdityaSanghi thanks for updating answer:) The problem here is, if I type 'ABC' into title, 'DEF' into body, and 'some word' into captcha field then click submit. It creates record fine with the flash message "Created" In my code, it looks there is no 'render' unless it matches captcha error. That's the point what I want to ask:)

Comment: Just to clarify again then, in case when captcha validation passes but the model \@topic validation fails, you do not see @topic validation errors in your view? Can you put a debugger on the line after \@topic.save? Does it reach there? Secondly how in your view are you displaying \@topic errors?

Comment: @AdityaSanghi Let me tell you something I'be just found.  It doesn't show validation error even if I comment out `before_filter :simple_captcha_check, :only => [:update, :create]`

Comment: Can you show more of your form view? how do you display errors on the form?

Comment: could you check see my update in answer? It's coded in `views/layouts/application.html.erb`

Comment: Well no!, the application layout only renders flash and flash does not automatically store your models' errors. For your errors to be displayed on the screen you need to write some code in your form.

Comment: Really? In my other page(model) validation error pops up... I'm so confused. So what can I write in my code to display this error message?

Comment: I had to put this `<%= render 'layouts/errors', object: @community, @topic %>`